# checking for a file in ftp server through shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

I've written a code in shell to retrieve the file of type "OLO2OLO_20170601_FATTURA.txt.zip" which is of current date.
Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/ksh

DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
FILE="OLO2OLO_$DATE_FATTURA.txt.zip"

/usr/bin/ftp -n 93.179.136.9 << !EOF!
user abc 1234
cd "/0009/Codici Migrazione"
get $FILE
bye
!EOF!
```

But I'm getting below error:

```
$ ./ftp_test1
Failed to open file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the variable name in curly brackets.

```
FILE="OLO2OLO_${DATE}_FATTURA.txt.zip"
```

An underscore is valid in a variable name. It is not a token separator.

Formally

> **name** is a word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and
>   underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an
>   underscore.

Currently shell is trying to substitute a value for a variable with name DATE_FATTURA which is empty so your `FILE` variable becomes `OLO2OLO_.txt.zip` Such file probably does not exist on the remote server.